# Is it the same way to add pythonw.exe on macOS as on Windows?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, conda

Just downloaded PyCharm and try to add a new project interpreter from conda environment. My mac shows no pythonw.exe options. How shall I fix this

[mine vs windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp2xY.jpg)

Sorry if my question are not very clear. more specifically:
I want to try a machine learning project and settle my computer ready for that. I just downloaded PyCharm, there are no interpreter so I cannot start. I wish to add a python interpreter to my PyCharm, (I knew the steps & knew for windows shall add file: pythonw.exe) but I cannot find any file similar to pythonw.exe, what file name shall Mac user choose? 
[python 3.6.10, conda 4.8.3]

Comment: There are no `.exe` files of **any** type on Macs, praise be given

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I was not exactly sure what you wanted to know from your question, I guess you are trying to use `conda` project in `PyCharm`. 
Did you try checking this [help guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/conda-support-creating-conda-virtual-environment.html) .
Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks very much for helping. I think I stuck at the help guide step3, points no.2. select python version, usually windows select pythonw.exe right? I have problem to find such a file on mac